# how to construct a query from an object using keys and values - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an object containing keys and values into a string of query, something like:

```
obj1: {
  abc: "Abc",
  id: 1,
  address: "something"
}.
```

however this object is dynamically created, hence the number and the keys in it may vary, like another obj dynamically could be;

```
obj1: {
  test: "123",
  test2: "3333"
}
```

whatever object does the server return I need to convert this into a string of query/; like

```
query1 = "test:'123'and test2: '3333'"
query2 = "abc:'Abc' and id: 1 and address: 'something'"
```

I could simpley try:

```
Object.keys(obj1)[0]
Object.keys(obj1)[1]
Object.keys(obj1)[2]
```

and get the keys and use:

```
Object.keys(obj1)[0]: obj1[Object.keys(obj1)[0]]
```

this would give me:

```
abc:'Abc'
```

however since the length of the keys in the object is not static and nor are the keys I'm finding it difficult to know how to concatenate these values into one string out of this
any idea?

Comment: If turning the object into an actual query string would suffice, it would perhaps allow you to use existing logic, rather than writing your own toString (essentially) method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; can't you just iterate over the object properties, build the string for each, and `join(' and ')`?

Comment: @DaveNewton The weirdness is with the quotes around only the string values.

Comment: @Taplar Ah; yes. You could stringify the value and interpolate the query value, though. Except the single quotes :/ So I guess by hand then.

Comment: How is this query used? Seems like a strange format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some minor inconsistencies in your format, but disregarding those you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) as follows:

```js
const objToQuery = o =>
  Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => 
    `${k}: ` + (typeof v === "number" ? v : `'${v}'`)
  ).join(" and ")
;

const obj1 = {
  abc: "Abc",
  id: 1,
  address: "something"
};
const obj2 = {
  test: "123",
  test2: "3333"
};
console.log(objToQuery(obj1));
console.log(objToQuery(obj2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just being a  bit creative here and using built in `URLSearchParams()` then replacing the `=` and the `&`. Not sure how important your quotes are as the other solution is more efficient if they are needed

```js
const obj1 = {
  abc: "Abc",
  id: 1,
  address: "something"
}

const objToQuery = o => {
  return (new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(o)))
    .toString().replace(/=/g, ': ').replace(/&/g, ' and ')
}



console.log(objToQuery(obj1))
```